# InputAccessoryView at UITableViewController inside UISplitViewController

Tags: swift, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm wondering how to implement simple "compose bar" inside `DetailsViewController` only.

```
//UITableViewController subclass

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView!{
    get {
        if (toolBar == nil) {
            toolBar = MyComposeBarView()
        }
        return toolBar
    }
}
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

By default `inputView` extends to whole screen including master and detail views of `UISplitController`

P.S. iMessages on iPad has exactly same compose bar as needed...